# one-to-many mapping of properties in java/groovy(files to devices)

Tags: java, groovy

I have a mapping of files and devies, as of now its one-to-one mapping.

Now I need to implement one-to-many mapping(single file to multiple devices)

my logic for one-to-one mapping is

```
deviceMapping = new Properties();
params.files.eachWithIndex { file, i ->
            def device = devices["${file.key}"]
            deviceMapping.put("${device}", "${file.value}");
        }
```

I have tried different ways which are not supporting my one-to-many mapping

1. I tried to loop through devices to map filess
2. tried to cut the string value of devices to map files

### current output

```
devices :[1.2:SonyEricsson X10i, 1:Samsung I9000 Galaxy, 0:Acer C6, 0.1:HTC Magic]

params files from screen :[0:TheSims3.apk, 1:Tetris.apk] 

device mapping :[Acer C6:TheSims3.apk, Samsung I9000 Galaxy:Tetris.apk]
```

what I want is :

```
[Acer C6:TheSims3.apk, Samsung I9000 Galaxy:Tetris.apk, SonyEricsson X10i:Tetris.apk, HTC Magic:TheSims3.apk]
```

Comment: What happened to `Motorola Droid Milestone` in your required output?

Comment: sorry...edited...it was a copy paste error while testing in different scenarios...glad you spotted it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explain how your mapping works...

But assuming you're mapping devices to files based on the first character of the device version(?), then given:

```
def devices = [ '1.2': 'SonyEricsson X10i',
                '1'  : 'Samsung I9000 Galaxy',
                '0'  : 'Acer C6',
                '0.1': 'HTC Magic' ]

def files = [ '0':'TheSims3.apk', '1':'Tetris.apk' ]
```

You can do something like:

```
def mapping = devices.collectEntries { ver, name ->
  // Get the first part of the version (up to the first dot)
  def v = ver.split( /\./ )[ 0 ]
  [ (name): files[ v ] ]
}
```

Or, if you are using a version of Groovy before 1.7.9, you can use `inject` in place of `collectEntries`:

```
def mapping = devices.inject( [:] ) { map, dev ->
  // Get the first part of the version (up to the first dot)
  def v = dev.key.split( /\./ )[ 0 ]
  map << [ (dev.value): files[ v ] ]
}
```

To give the variable `mapping` which will be set to:

```
[ "SonyEricsson X10i":"Tetris.apk",
  "Samsung I9000 Galaxy":"Tetris.apk",
  "Acer C6":"TheSims3.apk",
  "HTC Magic":"TheSims3.apk" ]
```

Comment: thanks Tim, but I am getting error No signature of method: java.util.Properties.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types, let me modify the code and update you

Comment: I am still getting the error "No signature of method: java.util.Properties.collectEntries() is applicable for argument types".

Comment: What version of Groovy are you on? Less than 1.7.9 I guess...  Updated with `inject` variant

Comment: groovy 1.8.2...not sure why it was not reflecting...is it because I am using free version of intellij IDEA? because few things did not work for me with community edition...let me test it with inject first and get back to you...

Comment: Ahhh....it's because `devices` is a `Properties` object, not a `Map` as in my example code...  One sec...

Comment: Actually, `Properties` is a `Map` so it should work...  Odd...  Fingers crossed `inject` covers it...